Circle fitting with points inside the circle
I have a noisy binarized image, in which most white points lay within a circle. What would be a good algorithm to fit the circle? The algorithm should be robust to handle all sorts of defects in the circle.
Here is an example image:

Here are some approaches I have tried so far:

Hough circles: not robust enough;
Dilate, find convex hull and fit the hull into a circle: not robust enough;
Several regular circle fitting algorithms - they can only fit with points on the circumference, not sure how to handle points inside the circle.
Calculate the distance of the white points pairwise, put them into a histogram and use otsu to find a "threshold", which matches the diameter of the circle. Too slow as there are tens of thousands of points.

Edit: attaching the original image here:

What I did to the original image to get the aforementioned binary image:

Make it grayscale;
Find and remove pixels too dark (mainly the two black curves, and no they are not allowed to be used as a hint of the circle to detect), replacing them with the median grayscale value of the image;
Binarize using Otsu threshold (inverted)
Fill holes - not significant on this image, but for images with denser content within the circle it helps a lot


Have you considered a RANSAC approach already? Something like "Given three bright pixels, assume the circle is their circumcircle. Validate by checking how many other bright pixels are right vs wrong under that assumption. Repeat many times, picking three at random."

@lucidbrot Yes I have given it a thought. The problem is, when randomly sampling points, it is much more likely I get points inside the circle rather than on its circumference. Points inside the circle does not contribute much to the model as far as I can see.

Maybe a genetic algorithm would be better (than purely random based RANSAC, with the circumference points kept as good chromosomes) but I'd like to check if there is a simpler approach first.

The method I would use would work better on the original gray-scale image (or a cleaned-up version of it). ---- We often get questions here where someone has gotten half-way in their image processing project, and ask how to continue. Often the first steps have made the problem harder, it's always worthwhile to go back to the start and re-evaluate the whole project. I think this is one of those cases.

@CrisLuengo good point, I've attached the original image. Would love to know your method.

what do we see? why is it circular at all? why is the circle not solid? why is the picture so dark? why does the non-circle area appear to be dirty? can you ensure that the circle is entirely within view? currently the circle is clipped, extending out of the picture.

How reliable is the level of noise outside the circle? What I'm getting at is: Could you erode heavily, to get rid of all non-circle points (and many circle-points) and then work with what remains?

@ChristophRackwitz It's a (macro) image of a microscopic specimen. It is circular because of the way the specimen is made. The picture is dark because the exposure time is relatively short, but I doubt longer exposure time would help in this case. The image is dirty is because its a photo of a real life object and, I guess, real life objects are oftentimes dirty.

@lucidbrot For the sake of robustness I can't erode too heavily, it eats up too much of the circle part in some scenarios.

@ChristophRackwich additional response to your editted comment: The circle is not solid also because of the way the specimen is made, it's called ThinPrep Test(TCT) in pathology. I can't guarantee that the circle would not be clipped, but I'm pretty sure most of the circle is in the view for all test cases.

This would be my approach. The initial result is not very good, it needs a bit more work. I'll detail next steps at the end.
Step 1: create a mask and prepare the image
The mask identifies the region inside the thick black circle, which I guess is the container. We want  to ensure that nothing outside of this influences our results.
import diplib as dip

# OP's original color image
img = dip.ImageRead("zDNIxW5n.jpg")
# We use the red channel, color information is not important and red has the best contrast
img = img(0)

# Find mask for analysis area by detecting the black circle (large dark areas)
approximate_radius = 400
circle = dip.AreaClosing(img, filterSize=10000)
gv = dip.Gradient(circle, 3)
circle = dip.OtsuThreshold(dip.Norm(gv))
x = dip.FindHoughCircles(circle, gv, range=[approximate_radius-100, approximate_radius+100], distance=100, fraction=0.9)
center = x[0][:2]
radius = x[0][2] - 20  # offset radius to ensure we clear out everything
mask = dip.DistanceToPoint(img.Sizes(), center, distance="square") < radius**2

# Prepare image
img = dip.Percentile(img, mask, percentile=95) - img
img.Mask(mask)

At the bottom of the post you can see what img looks like now.
Step 2: an initial estimate of the center of the circle
# Find centroid
center = dip.CenterOfMass(img)

This center is not exact because the matter in the circle is not distributed uniformly, and there is some signal outside the circle as well.
Step 3: an initial estimate of the radius of the circle
For this, we create a sum projection of the image as a function of the distance to the centroid we found above.
# Find radius, as the first point where the sum projection gets to half its maximum
proj = dip.RadialSum(img, center=center)
max_pos = dip.PositionMaximum(proj)[0][0]
max_val = proj[max_pos][0]
x = (proj < max_val / 2) & (dip.CreateXCoordinate(proj.Sizes(), mode={"corner"}) > max_pos)
radius = dip.PositionMaximum(x, mode="first")[0][0]

The proj function looks like this:

As the distance to the center increases, the sum increases also. Outside the circle, where there is little gray-values, the sum should be close to 0.
We take as the radius the point after the maximum where the sum reaches half the maximum value.
Because our initial center is not the actual center, the downward slope at this point is not very steep. If we find the actual center, then the slope would be very steep.
The initial center and radius look like this:
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img.Show()
c = mpl.patches.Circle(center, radius=radius, fill=False, edgecolor='r')
plt.gca().add_patch(c)
plt.show()


So at this point we could do an iterative refinement, where we move the centroid to make that slope as steep as possible. This involves repeatedly computing step 3, and evaluating the steepness of proj at max_pos (for example by comparing the values at max_pos - 2 and max_pos + 2, or fitting a straight line through a few points around max_pos).
Also note that improving the sample preparation and imaging will make the problem easier. Often we get asked to solve a problem where the imaging protocol has already been established. But often going back and fixing that converts the image analysis from a hard problem to a trivial one. Things to improve would be reducing the air or glue under the cover slip, or whatever it is that creates those lines, including the full container (such that the black circle is complete, making the mask code a one-liner), and properly adjusting the illumination.

PS: I'm using DIPlib in Python for this demo. I'm an author of DIPlib..

For starters we can't exploit the two arcs, because they are not always there. I'll think about the centeroid refinement process but I have a feeling it also has robustness issues.

Here is my take to this problem.
The idea is to use the DBSCAN algorithm to cluster the image, take the biggest cluster and fit a minimum enclosing circle to it. We use a fixed, fine tuned minPts parameter, and try to find the best epsilon parameter: starting with a relatively large epsilon value, find the biggest cluster, fit a circle, and calculate the fullness of the circle (number of white points contained by the circle divided by the area of the circle). Repeat this procedure with epsilon decrementing, until we see the fullness value peaks.
Because with a large epsilon value, it's very likely that the fitted circle contains noises outside of the expected area, there will be more "empty space" in the fitted circle, therefore less fullness. As the epsilon decrements, we get to a point where the fitted circle best matches the expected area, resulting a maximum fullness.
Because we know the ballpark size of the expected area, we also use this knowledge to filter out circles with undesired radius.
As we can see in the following picture, with this approach, we get the best fit when epsilon = 7 (green: points in the biggest cluster, red: fitted circle).

